# noUiSlider "Must pass a formatter for all handles" with tooltip formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

When i try and format the decimal places of the tooltip i get the following error. Unsure why as im copy pasting the tooltip line from the documentation.

"Uncaught Error: noUiSlider: must pass a formatter for all handles."

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var frequencySlider = document.getElementById('frequencySlider');

noUiSlider.create(frequencySlider, {
    start: [ 4 ],
    step: 1,
    range: {
        'min': [  1 ],
        'max': [ 40 ]
    },
        tooltips: [true, wNumb({ decimals: 1 })],
    pips: {
        mode: 'values',
        values: [1, 10, 20, 30, 40],
        density: 100,
        stepped: true,
    }

});



var frequencyNumber = document.getElementById('rangePickerTextMonthly');

frequencySlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

    var value = values[handle];
        frequencyNumber.value = value;
            optionChange();
});



frequencyNumber.addEventListener('change', function(){
    frequencySlider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
});

});
```

Answer (score 7):

The start option sets the number of handles and corresponding start positions. 
In your example, you have two tooltips formatter

```
    tooltips: [true, wNumb({ decimals: 1 })]
```

Instead you need one for your only handle

```
    tooltips: [true]
```

Or

```
    tooltips: [ wNumb({ decimals: 1 })]
```

If you want to show tooltips for all Handles just use tooltips : true and if not use tooltips : false

Comment: how I can use tooltip but with dates?

Comment: I would like more information for what you want to achieve so i can help you. You have to create a formatter
 e.g.   {
   to: function ( value ) {
  return  value;
   },
   from: Number;
   }

Comment: or  

    tooltips: [ wNumb({ decimals: 1 }), wNumb({ decimals: 1 })]